# How to get order cancel date in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Im working on a order feed. How to get the date on the order that is canceled in Magento as well as the ship date when a tracking number is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the order cancel date you can parse the order comments and get date of the first `Canceled` status of the comment like so:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(100000050);

$commentCollection = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection();

foreach ($commentCollection as $comment) {    
  if ($comment->getStatus() === Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED) {
    $orderCancelDate = $comment->getCreatedAt();
  }
}

echo $orderCancelDate;
```

Output:

```
2014-02-11 03:43:09 <- Date\time order was marked `Canceled`
```

To get the shipping date/time(s) of the order and the date/times(s) of when the tracking number was updated you can get everything like so:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(100000054);

$shipmentCollection = $order->getShipmentsCollection();

foreach ($shipmentCollection as $shipment) {

  // Date/Time when order shipment(s) were created
  echo $shipment->getCreatedAt() . "<br />";

  foreach($shipment->getAllTracks() as $trackingNumber) {

    // Date/Time when the tracking number(s) were updated
    echo $trackingNumber->getUpdatedAt();

    // Date/Time when the tracking number(s) were added
    // echo $trackingNumber->getCreatedAt();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2014-02-11 05:35:10 <- Date\time order was marked `Shipped`
2014-02-11 05:35:38 <- Date\time tracking number(s) were updated
```

Just remember, an order can have multiple partial shipments and multiple tracking numbers per partial shipments which is why you have to loop through them all to get the correct date\time(s).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The  `Mage::getModel('sales/order')` model contain all sales and order details.
You can use this ,
consider '**10003**' is the order no,

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(10003);
$_totalData = $order->getData();
print_r($_totalData);
```

$_totalData will then contain the following:

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 45
    [state] => processing
    [status] => pending
    [coupon_code] => stickytest
    [protect_code] => 1036b0
    [shipping_description] => Voucher code discount
    [is_virtual] => 0
    [store_id] => 1
    [customer_id] =>
    [base_discount_amount] => -195.0000
    [base_discount_canceled] =>
    [base_discount_invoiced] =>
    [base_discount_refunded] =>
    [base_grand_total] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_canceled] =>
    [base_shipping_invoiced] =>
    [base_shipping_refunded] =>
    [base_shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_tax_refunded] =>
    [base_subtotal] => 177.2700
    [base_subtotal_canceled] =>
    [base_subtotal_invoiced] =>
    [base_subtotal_refunded] =>
    [base_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_tax_canceled] =>
    [base_tax_invoiced] =>
    [base_tax_refunded] =>
    [base_to_global_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
    [base_total_canceled] =>
    [base_total_invoiced] =>
    [base_total_invoiced_cost] =>
    [base_total_offline_refunded] =>
    [base_total_online_refunded] =>
    [base_total_paid] =>
    [base_total_qty_ordered] =>
    [base_total_refunded] =>
    [discount_amount] => -195.0000
    [discount_canceled] =>
    [discount_invoiced] =>
    [discount_refunded] =>
    [grand_total] => 0.0000
    [shipping_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_canceled] =>
    [shipping_invoiced] =>
    [shipping_refunded] =>
    [shipping_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [shipping_tax_refunded] =>
    [store_to_base_rate] => 1.0000
    [store_to_order_rate] => 1.0000
    [subtotal] => 177.2700
    [subtotal_canceled] =>
    [subtotal_invoiced] =>
    [subtotal_refunded] =>
    [tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [tax_canceled] =>
    [tax_invoiced] =>
    [tax_refunded] =>
    [total_canceled] =>
    [total_invoiced] =>
    [total_offline_refunded] =>
    [total_online_refunded] =>
    [total_paid] =>
    [total_qty_ordered] => 1.0000
    [total_refunded] =>
    [can_ship_partially] =>
    [can_ship_partially_item] =>
    [customer_is_guest] => 1
    [customer_note_notify] => 1
    [billing_address_id] => 89
    [customer_group_id] => 0
    [edit_increment] =>
    [email_sent] => 1
    [forced_shipment_with_invoice] =>
    [gift_message_id] =>
    [payment_auth_expiration] =>
    [paypal_ipn_customer_notified] =>
    [quote_address_id] =>
    [quote_id] => 215
    [shipping_address_id] => 90
    [adjustment_negative] =>
    [adjustment_positive] =>
    [base_adjustment_negative] =>
    [base_adjustment_positive] =>
    [base_shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_subtotal_incl_tax] => 195.0000
    [base_total_due] =>
    [payment_authorization_amount] =>
    [shipping_discount_amount] => 0.0000
    [subtotal_incl_tax] => 195.0000
    [total_due] =>
    [weight] => 1.0000
    [customer_dob] =>
    [increment_id] => 100000034
    [applied_rule_ids] => 4
    [base_currency_code] => AUD
    [customer_email] => someone@somewhere.com
    [customer_firstname] => billing[firstname]
    [customer_lastname] => billing[lastname]
    [customer_middlename] =>
    [customer_prefix] =>
    [customer_suffix] =>
    [customer_taxvat] =>
    [discount_description] => stickytest
    [ext_customer_id] =>
    [ext_order_id] =>
    [global_currency_code] => AUD
    [hold_before_state] =>
    [hold_before_status] =>
    [order_currency_code] => AUD
    [original_increment_id] =>
    [relation_child_id] =>
    [relation_child_real_id] =>
    [relation_parent_id] =>
    [relation_parent_real_id] =>
    [remote_ip] => 192.168.0.18
    [shipping_method] => matrixrate_matrixrate_free
    [store_currency_code] => AUD
    [store_name] => Main Website
Main Store
English
    [x_forwarded_for] =>
    [customer_note] =>
    [created_at] => 2012-11-19 10:53:11
    [updated_at] => 2012-11-19 10:53:12
    [total_item_count] => 1
    [customer_gender] =>
    [base_custbalance_amount] =>
    [currency_base_id] =>
    [currency_code] =>
    [currency_rate] =>
    [custbalance_amount] =>
    [is_hold] =>
    [is_multi_payment] =>
    [real_order_id] =>
    [tax_percent] =>
    [tracking_numbers] =>
    [hidden_tax_amount] => 17.7300
    [base_hidden_tax_amount] => 17.7300
    [shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt] => 0.0000
    [hidden_tax_invoiced] =>
    [base_hidden_tax_invoiced] =>
    [hidden_tax_refunded] =>
    [base_hidden_tax_refunded] =>
    [shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [base_shipping_incl_tax] => 0.0000
    [onestepcheckout_customercomment] => onestepcheckout_comments
    [onestepcheckout_customerfeedback] => Google
    [payment_authorization_expiration] =>
    [forced_do_shipment_with_invoice] =>
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
)
```

For more information follow this [link](http://code.marksserver.co.uk/magento/orders/magento-get-order-details/871/) ..

Comment: Hi, Ive seen this method using var_dump. But it doesnt have order cancel date in it other than created and updated date. So should I use updated date and check status on the order to be "cancel" and use that instead? thanks